# Why do two of the same strings not return as being the same when compared?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
file = open('AdjectivesList.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

for word in words:
    wordLowercase = word.lower()
    for x, lol in enumerate(lines):
       gg = (lines[x].lower())
       if wordLowercase == gg:
            print('identified')
```

Even when `wordLowercase` does equal `gg`, the string "identified" is not being printed. Why is this the case?

Comment: There're maybe some unprintable characters?

Comment: `lines[x].lower()` is just `lol.lower()`.

Comment: Please try `gg = lines[x].lower().strip` instead of `gg = lines[x].lower()` only. There might be some whitespace characters that gets included in `gg`. I suggest going for @Austin's remark and use `lol.lower()` instead of `lines[x].lower()`.

Comment: I think you can do away with `enumerate` and just use `for line in lines:`. That way, you won't need to use `lines[x]` and just need to use `line`.

Comment: Maybe instead of `gg = (lines[x].lower())` do `gg = lol.lower().strip()`

Comment: Erratum in my first comment. It's supposed to be `gg = lines[x].lower().strip()` and not `gg = lines[x].lower().strip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.readlines()` includes the newline character at the end of every line in the text file. This is most likely the cause of your problem. You can remove the newline character (and any whitespace characters from the left and right of the string) by using `.strip()`.

```
gg = lines[x].lower().strip()
```

**Reference**

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm